# SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome-beta/nacl_helper from getattr access on the file /etc/passwd

Tags: google-chrome, selinux, google-chrome-beta

I'm not sure why and/or if it's normal, but I keep getting popup from my `SELinux Alert Browser`:

> SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome-beta/nacl_helper from getattr
>   access on the file /etc/passwd.

I placed details into [nacl_helper - Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/fmACNFZx).

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 03:04:26 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -q google-chrome-beta selinux-policy
google-chrome-beta-43.0.2357.45-1.x86_64
selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[0008789: SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper from 'getattr' accesses on the file /etc/passwd. - CentOS Bug Tracker](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8789)

workaround:

```
$ sudo setsebool -P unconfined_chrome_sandbox_transition 0
$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1204307). Seems safe to ignore.